# Matlab data sampler that weights the outputs to binary (0,1)

Tags: matlab, sampling

a sample probability matrix:

```
ans =

    0.1444    0.0456    0.0138    0.0126    0.0116    0.0107    0.0052
    0.1444    0.0456    0.0138    0.0126    0.0116    0.0107    0.0052
    0.1222    0.0386    0.0116    0.0106    0.0098    0.0091    0.0044
    0.1444    0.0456    0.0138    0.0126    0.0116    0.0107    0.0052
    0.1222    0.0386    0.0116    0.0106    0.0098    0.0091    0.0044
    0.1889    0.0596    0.0180    0.0164    0.0151    0.0140    0.0067
    0.1333    0.0421    0.0127    0.0116    0.0107    0.0099    0.0048
```

I have used `dataSample` and `randSample` to sample 128 time from my data which has `A=(7,7)` size in matlab:

```
datasample(A,128)


ans =

    0.1333    0.0421    0.0127    0.0116    0.0107    0.0099    0.0048
    0.1222    0.0386    0.0116    0.0106    0.0098    0.0091    0.0044
    0.1889    0.0596    0.0180    0.0164    0.0151    0.0140    0.0067
    0.1889    0.0596    0.0180    0.0164    0.0151    0.0140    0.0067
    0.1333    0.0421    0.0127    0.0116    0.0107    0.0099    0.0048
    0.1444    0.0456    0.0138    0.0126    0.0116    0.0107    0.0052
    0.1222    0.0386    0.0116    0.0106    0.0098    0.0091    0.0044
    ...
```

However, I am interested in having those 128 sample of 7 `(128,7)` in binary format with two discrete values of 0 and 1:

`[1 1 1 0 1 0 1]`

I can write a loop and round-down/up those values to 0 and 1 with certain thresholds (i.e. 0.5), but that for sure will be noisy. Is there a function that can output the sampling in binary (0,1) in Matlab ?

Comment: It is a little unclear what you mean by binary format. Do you want to apply a threshold to your data or you do you literally want a binary representation of each number? Or do you simply want to know where in A the output came from?

Comment: sorry for being unclear, i revised the question. I meant the output format should be either 0 or 1

Comment: right, but your input data is clearly *not* binary, so what transform are you hoping to use to convert it to binary?

Comment: Yes, still not clear. How do you want to convert it to binary ?

Comment: These are a probability model derived by a MarkovChain model I constructed, I am interested in sample these probabilities to come up with prediction for certain variables and they are (0,1).

Comment: Maybe setting a threshold might help (if I understood correctly). Something like `if value < 0.5 then set value to 0; if value >= 0.5 then set value to 1.` where `0.5` is your threshold. That's just a pseudocode to explain my idea: you can use either a loop or some smarter ways, that's up to you.

Comment: To simplify @Alessiox post: `result = datasample(A, 128) >= 0.5`

Comment: I know I can do that as I explained in the question, that will be noisy. I need a binary discrete sample that weights these.

Comment: No. There's no way to accomplish this. `datasample()` returns samples from your input matrix `A`. If `A` contains floating point numbers, then `datasample()` will return floating point numbers as well. Such floating point numbers are probability values, so it's ok for them to be floating point numbers in range [0;1]. I'm afraid you have to do the thresholding manually in order to hard-limit them as 0 or 1.

Comment: I see. Maybe I should see the mean and median of the distribution and set the threshold to that point, _OR_ first normalize the probabilities to [0,1] to be more uniform and then set that 0.5 to have fair results.

Comment: I really suggest the mean value of your distribution, without rescaling. In this manner you'll always have your original Markov Chain values. However, since we're talking about sampling & distributions, the more points (samples) you can get, the more accurate the mean value will be. You can then start form @Suever's code but instead of 0.5 you can set the `datasample()` mean value. `ExtractedValues=datasample(A,128); result=ExtractedValues>mean(ExtractedValues(:));`

Comment: yes. thats correct. thanks